# Уменьшить размер share.js подгружаемый блоком Поделиться

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Здравствуйте!

Есть ли возможность убрать из кода подгружаемого share.js фрагменты относящиеся к неиспользуемым на сайте кнопкам. Просто он очень большой и если убрать лишние base64, то существенно уменьшится.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Такой возможности нет.

Если критичен размер загружаемого контента, можно реализовать социальные кнопки самостоятельно.

Необходимые стили, разметку и адреса соцсетей можно позаимствовать из блока "Поделиться", а JavaScript-код в таком случае будет не нужен.

Единственный недостаток: поддерживать блок – своевременно обновлять иконки и следить за изменением API соцсетей – теперь придётся самостоятельно.